# How can write and indicator function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pde

I want to make an indicator function for pde in Python u(x) = 2*x if 0<x<1/2 and 2-2*x if 1/2<x<1
but when i do it an error occurs.

I have chosen the np.where which is a if else function.

Can someone help me?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,1)
x
np.where(x>0 & x<1/2,2*x,2-2*x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be really helpful if you provided the error message instead of just saying "an error occurs".

Anyway, add parentheses, i.e. `(x>0) & (x<0.5)`. You need them because the `&` operator has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the comparison operators, so in `x>0 & x<0.5`, the first expression to be evaluated is `0 & x`. The error message complains that this is not valid when `x` is a NumPy array.

PS: This is not an indicator function.

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I'm not asking for the error for myself. I know what it is. I'm telling you that it's useful to provide the error when asking a question like this.